# Why do most natural language processing papers fail to give any significance test when reporting results?

Tags: statistical-significance, natural-language

Most natural language processing papers (> 90% from my experience) fail to give any significance test when reporting results. Is there any reason for that aside from the fact that it takes a bit of time to run them?

Comment: What would you like to test for significance in the algorithms?

Comment: @Aksakal To see whether they "truly" improved over existing methods.

Comment: That's not done with significance testing even in the non-NLP applications. It's out-of-sample like metrics, accuracy, recall etc.

Comment: @Aksakal E.g. to test the significance of the difference between two F1-scores.

Comment: I don't think anyone associates $F_1$ scores with test statistics

Comment: @Aksakal E.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046415001173 Stubbs, Amber, Christopher Kotfila, and Özlem Uzuner. "Automated systems for the de-identification of longitudinal clinical narratives: Overview of 2014 i2b2/UTHealth shared task Track 1." Journal of biomedical informatics 58 (2015): S11-S19. "We used precision (Eq. (1)), recall (Eq. (2)) and F-measure (Eq. (3)) scores to evaluate the participants’ results against the gold standard annotations. We checked the significance of the differences of the systems from each other using approximate randomization"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you (percentage estimate included). The reason is that the historically most prominent NLP tasks (tokenization, part-of-speech tagging) use relatively big dataset. Many times those are big enough to make a 0.1% difference in F1 measure statistically significant. The rest of the literature, many times, follows.